# how to fetch stock market data values continuously

Tags: yql, stock, yahoo-finance

I am developing a B.E level project and want to fetch the stock market data continuously and populate it in my local server(possibly oracle) on my machine.
The doubt is that how to do this?
Do I need to write a javascript or some other code which will continuously fetch the data?
Or then how is it possible that my machine starts fetching the data as soon as my machine is on.
I am thinking of using YQL/yahoo-finance-api for fetching the Stock Quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the YQL API calling HTTP get with the YQL statement as a parameter, so you don't have to use javascript (and I wouldn't recommend it, since it runs on the client's machine).  You should create a server-side script to accomplish this, use whatever language you like.  Making the script run at start-up depends on what OS you are using.

Comment: If I am thinking of using a oracle or glassfish server which server side scripting language would be recomended. And how come I make the script run when I start my machine(running windows 7) or the server automatically.